# firebase cloud firestore pricing on batch operations

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

If we use the batch API to write something to firestore, is it going to be counted as a single write operation on pricing >

Answer (score 16):

No. You are still charged for each individual document write.

Comment: Does overwriting identical data on a document count as another write? Since Firestore doesn't have to update its index.

Comment: you broke my heart by this answer 

Comment: @MujtabaFR but their wallet is getting filled  

Comment: If I have multiple changes on multiple documents (and some of changes are on the same document). And, I call batch's commit only once in the end of the changes, am I charged for every change operation or it charges me for just one operation?