# Cloud Firestore: does updating the same document twice in a batch count as a single write?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update one field and, in some case, another field of the same document in a batch:

```
db.runBatch { batch ->
    val myRef = db.document("path/to/document")
    batch.update(myRef, "foo", "bar")

    if(someCondition) {
        batch.update(myRef, "baz", "bar")
    }
}
```

Is this billed as a single write or as two writes in case `someCondition` is true?

As an alternative I could do something like this:

```
db.runBatch { batch ->
    val myRef = db.document("path/to/document")

    if(someCondition) {
        batch.update(myRef, "foo", "bar", "baz", "bar")
    } else {
        batch.update(myRef, "foo", "bar")
    }
}
```

But that leads to duplicating code and becomes very messy in case of updating more fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be only one write, but this is very easy to work around if you don't have confidence in that.  Just take a different approach where you build the Map of updates just once, and pass the to [update()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/WriteBatch#update(com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference,%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E)) which takes a Map:

```
db.runBatch { batch ->
    val myRef = db.document("path/to/document")
    val obj = if (someCondition) {
        mapOf("foo" to "bar", "baz" to "bar")
    }
    else {
        mapOf("foo" to "bar")
    }

    batch.update(myRef, obj)
}
```

Comment: So in case, I use the first approach, I will only get billed for one document write?

Comment: You should only get billed once, but if you have concerns, call update only once.  Contact Firebase support directly for further questions about billing. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48435979/firebase-cloud-firestore-pricing-on-batch-operations it says you are charged for each write and in the docs it says for each write..

Comment: @PeterHaddad That refers to transactions, and it only applies to each unique document written in the transaction.

Comment: Op in the question said the batch API "If we use the batch API to write something to firestore, is it going to be counted as a single write operation on pricing"... The URL links contains transaction and batch guide

Comment: @PeterHaddad That's because they're just documented on the same page.  In any event, the SDK keeps track of all the changes to make at once before sending it to the server to be processed atomically. Neither a batch or a transaction complete any way other than atomically, with each document being written exactly once.  My answer addresses any possibly ambiguity by proposing code that only chooses to update a single document a single time in the batch.

Comment: We could challenge the fact that we still need a batch. With your approach @DougStevenson, a simple write is sufficient IMHO (if there isn't any other write/update/delete to be added to the batch).

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I never said a batch wasn't necessary.  The OP gave an abstract situation.  We don't know exactly what this batch contains.  As stated, only a single document was updated in two places within a single batch.  The batch is not sent to the server until commit() is called, at which point all documents are affected atomically (in other words, a single write per document with all changes on that doc), or not at all.

Comment: @DougStevenson Indeed Doug! Due to the way my comment was written, it was maybe not clear enough that it was more a constructive remark, a kind of extra info to be possibly added to your anwser :-)